# Browser cannot be initialized error when request for a certificate with tizen-sdk

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-mobile-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear, tizen-sdk

When I try to request for a new certificate with tizen-sdk 2.4.0_Rev5 in `Register Certificate`, I get the following error `Browser cannot be initialized`.

I changed the path to chrome in `Preferences->Tizen SDK->Web->Chrome` to fit my actual path, and it works well with the simulator. I am using linux and I tried with `chromium` and `google-chrome-stable`.

Comment: Does your Chrome is installed in the default path or in different location?and also check the Extra parameters: --no-first-run --activate-on-launch --no-default-browser-check --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security --disable-translate --proxy-auto-detect --proxy-bypass-list=127.0.0.1

Comment: As I said I changed the default path to my chrome path. I checked the options too. And for the simulator chrome is found.

Comment: Usually the default path is: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome, so changing the default path may create the problem.

Comment: I do not get your comment. Anyway, I have an installation of google-chrome in `/opt/google/chrome/' and it does not work for the registration (but for the simulation it is okay).

Comment: I am referring that "The Google Chrome™ browser location is automatically set as default if the Chrome™ browser is installed in your system.
In case you install the browser in a custom path, the IDE cannot automatically detect the path and you must set the location manually."
Help Link: https://developer.tizen.org/development/tools/web-tools/ide-preferences?langswitch=en

Comment: At which step are you seeing the "Browser cannot be initialized" error?

Comment: I click on `Create new certificate`, fill in the form, and the message appears when I click on `Request`.

Comment: If your problem still continues, then I would suggest you to uninstall and re-install the Tizen SDK, and before re-install then delete all tizen-sdk & tizen-sdk-data folder. That might help you.

Comment: I did try that, but without any results. And it is the same with the installation of rev6.

Answer (score 2):

libwebkitgtk-1.0 is needed for internal browser. to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mac, I have these settings in Tizen IDE for Chrome:

[image]

Could you please double check the `Extra parameters` list:

```
--no-first-run --activate-on-launch --no-default-browser-check --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security --disable-translate --proxy-auto-detect --proxy-bypass-list=127.0.0.1
```